# Could not resolve host: While Trying to Connect to a Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes

I have two services in kubernetes sharing the same namespace.

I am trying to connect to `service B` from inside a pod that is associated with `service A`.

I exec into the pod that is associated with `service A` then try to send `curl` request to `service B`:

```
curl service-b-beta.common-space.svc.cluster.local:7000
```

However, it returns the following error:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: service-b-beta.common-space.svc.cluster.local
```

service A:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    name: service-a
  namespace: common-space
  name: service-a-beta
spec:
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 7200
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 7200
  selector:
    name: service-a-beta
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
```

Service B:

```
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: service-b
      namespace: common-space
      name: service-b-beta
    spec:
      ports:
      - name: http
        port: 7000
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 7000
      selector:
        name: service-b-beta
      sessionAffinity: None
      type: ClusterIP
```

Comment: There are a lot of missing details here required to find the root cause of your issue - how are you managing dns inside your kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some debugging tips:

1. If running on multiple nodes, please make sure nodes can talk to each other.
2. Check if `coredns` pod on `master` is running and is healthy. See logs for any issues.
3. Run a test pod in the cluster and see if you can resolve internet domains. If failing then check your `coredns` for logs.
4. Run a test pod and check /etc/resolve.conf and see if it makes sense.
5. Check `coredns` config map in the system namespace. See if it looks normal
6. Describe the endpoints of the target service and see if it's bound correctly to the target pod.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that `svc.cluster.local` is not the parent domain. As the 2 services are in the same namespace, you can just do this:

```
curl service-b-beta:7000
```